# Addition with the same prompt, but different values

Tags: javascript, function, for-loop, average, addition

For a task I have to create four sets of averages, each set using 3 input values. I have the user able to put values and four sets being displayed, but the averages aren't being displayed. Does anyone know why? My code is displayed below.

NOTE - I have this task completed using one loop and variables, but I'm told I should be using two, just in-case anyone tries to suggest that.

```
    function inputTime () {
        var delayTime = parseInt(prompt("Delay time is:", "0 seconds"));
    }   

    function performanceTest() {        

        for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
          parseInt(inputTime());
        }

        var delayTimeAvg = (inputTime)/3;

      document.write("The average delay time is:" +" " + delayTimeAvg);
      } 

    function fourTests () {

        for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
          performanceTest();
        }
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: I am assuming the error is in averaging the values, but i don't know how to properly write it to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first, your inputTime function does not return any value; second, inputTime is not a number.
this is the correct code

```
        function inputTime() {
        return  parseInt(prompt("Delay time is:", "0 seconds"));
    }

    function performanceTest() {
        var inputValue = 0;
        for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            inputValue += inputTime();
        }

        var delayTimeAvg = (inputValue) / 3;

        document.write("The average delay time is:" + " " + delayTimeAvg + "<br/>");
    }

    function fourTests() {

        for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            performanceTest();
        }
    }
```

Comment: This doesn't work, the value for delayTimeAvg comes up as NaN.

Comment: It works with me in mozilla, can tell what kind of data you enter in the prompt box??

Comment: Integers, do I need to change input value to parseInt as well?

Comment: If the prompt box contains integers, it should work. because it is the same i did, check if you realy copied my code. I advice you to completly replace your code. the change were made in many parts

Comment: Yeah its working now, I must have not copied it all over correctly. Thanks for your help and speedy replies!